# AppleScript not getting URL or webpage title in Safari

Tags: safari, applescript

I am trying to do the following in Safari: I have a website opened (let's say http://www.example.org) and I'm trying to get the current tab by using applescript.

I tried the following:

```
delay 1
tell application "Safari"
    set mytitle to name of current tab in window 1
end tell
display alert mytitle
```

However I get the following error message
Safari got an error: AppleEvent handler failed.

I tried with all sorts of variations, URL of current tab in window 1, name of current tab, with and without window 1...
But the error persists.

After a bit of consoling it came up with this error:
Console returns this: Error while returning the result of a script command: the result object... lol - Buscar con Google ...could not be converted to an Apple event descriptor of type 'text'. This instance of the class '__NSCFString' returned nil when sent -objectSpecifier (is it not overridden?) and there is no coercible type declared for the scripting class 'text'. 
What am I doing wrong?
I'd appreciate any ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Code works for me. Are you *sure* the error is in this spot? Reduce your script to the specific line where it breaks.

Comment: Yes. It works for my friend too. Have a look at this. I typed 'lol' into Spanish google. Console returns this: Error while returning the result of a script command: the result object... lol - Buscar con Google ...could not be converted to an Apple event descriptor of type 'text'. This instance of the class '__NSCFString' returned nil when sent -objectSpecifier (is it not overridden?) and there is no coercible type declared for the scripting class 'text'.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set mytitle to name of current tab in window 1
end tell

return mytitle
```

Answer (score 0):

The first script I posted did indeed work... There was a systemwide error and clean install fixed it. Not sure what was going on. Thanks everyone.